# Google Places Autocomplete - how to get Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: ios, autocomplete, google-places-api

I use URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=bar&key=API_KEY&types=geocode
```

What should I do to retrieve data with places location (Latitude and Longitude)?

Comment: you have to generate API_KEY at googlemaps developer. then pass API_KEY in your url. you have to sign up and create key using (https://developers.google.com/maps/signup)

Comment: i know, i passed it. It works. I receive the places from Google, but  there is no information about location.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is not possible ONLY with this URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=bar&key=API_KEY
```

All I needed to do was to get `place_id` from response, and then use it in NEXT following URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?input=bar&placeid=PLACE_ID&key=API_KEY
```

Where:

**PLACE_ID** - retrieved `place_id` from previous request.

**API_KEY** - my key generated by Google to use with my app.

`autocomplete` must be replaced with `details` in above URL's.

Comment: Appreciate your answer mate :)

Comment: The result[0] i receive back is  lat: function () & lng function () , i don't get the values.

Comment: figured it out, the functions return the values :)

Answer (score 5):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=bar&key=API_KEY
```

Then get `place_id` and call following function to get data

```
let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
    func GetPlaceDataByPlaceID(pPlaceID: String)
    {
      //  pPlaceID = "ChIJXbmAjccVrjsRlf31U1ZGpDM"
        self.placesClient.lookUpPlaceID(pPlaceID, callback: { (place, error) -> Void in

            if let error = error {
                print("lookup place id query error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if let place = place {
                print("Place name \(place.name)")
                print("Place address \(place.formattedAddress!)")
                print("Place placeID \(place.placeID)")
                print("Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
                print("\(place.coordinate.latitude)")
                print("\(place.coordinate.longitude)")
            } else {
                print("No place details for \(pPlaceID)")
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Its throwing an internal error.. Do you have any other approach?

Comment: It is giving me this error 
error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
    "errors": [
        "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",

Answer (score 3):

This is actually called as "Google Places Autocomplete" not "Maps autocomplete". You get place id from there, you need to call Google places api to retrieve the details info including locations, etc.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

Or you can use Place Search api as your needs.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search